Limit of a Lagrange interpolating polynomial
My mid-term examination on Numerical methods had a question about interpolation that I found confusing about:
Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Let $0 < \epsilon < 1$ and consider the three data values $(0, f(0)), (\epsilon, f(\epsilon)),$ and $(1, f(1))$. Let $q$ be the polynomial that arises as the limit of the second-order polynomial interpolating 1  the data as $\epsilon \to 0$.

What is the degree of $q$?
What data (if any) does $q$ interpolate?
What data (if any) does $q'$ interpolate?

What I've done so far:
I found the polynomial as usual and it is of degree 2 (because there are 3 points). Then I consider $\epsilon$ as a variable and apply L'Hospital Rule to find the limit. Then I obtained $q=x^2.(f(1)-f(0)-f'(0))+x.f'(0)+f(0)$. I concluded that q is of degree 2.
So am I doing the right thing? I'm uncertain whether considering $\epsilon$ as a variable and x as a constant is correct.

You can do so since $\mathbb R_2[x]$ is a dim 3 real vector space

$q(0)=f(0), q(1)=f(1), q'(0)=f'(0)$

I already obtained that, but what i struggle with is the part of finding the limit. Is there any other way to obtain the limit rather than L'Hospital Rule?

@KhanhLinh Instead of using the L'Hôpital's rule., you can use the definition of derivative of $f$ at 0, as $f$ is smooth: $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\dfrac{f(\varepsilon) - f(0)}{\varepsilon} = f'(0)$
